# Допустимая частота запросов к API StackExchange?

Tags: обсуждение

Я написал следующий код для проверки наличия сообщений в очереди проверок (python):

```
import request, os
empty = <empty queue html code goes here>
while True:
    if request.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts').text != empty:
        print('An item detected!')
        os.system('say "An item was found!"')
```

Я и не сообразил, что это какая-то DDOS атака...
И мне временно ограничили доступ.
Какая допустимая частота запросов к API SE?

Comment: справка: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle

Comment: Ограничение не больше: 30 rps с одного ip

Comment: А нафига подобную проверку вообще делать чаще раза в пять секунд?

Comment: Не нужно откатывать улучшающие правки. Кроме того, в заголовке про API, а в коде запрос к URL, который отдает обычный HTML - это совсем не "API". Про что именно все же речь?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, что-то не вижу принципиальных улучшений.

Comment: @Qwertiy me too

Comment: @Qwertiy как минимум исправление "ддос" на "DDOS" является объективным улучшением, так как это орфографическая ошибка. Заимствованные аббревиатуры пишутся большими буквами.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight По-моему нет разницы: ну большими, ну маленькими... А зато до этого было написано нормальным человеческим языком без выпендрежа, а то "ограничили доступ", "Допустимая частота" ...

Comment: @Qwertiy (see upper)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grundy правильно в комментариях указал на ограничение в 30 запросов с одного IP в секунду.

Однако, согласно [той же странице](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) кроме уже указанного

> If a single IP is making more than 30 requests a second, new requests will be dropped. The exact ban period is subject to change, but will be on the order of 30 seconds to a few minutes typically. Note that exactly what response an application gets (in terms of HTTP code, text, and so on) is undefined when subject to this ban; we consider **> 30 request/sec per IP to be very abusive** and thus cut the requests off very harshly.

есть также

> While not strictly a throttle, the API employs heavy caching and as such no application should make semantically identical requests more than once a minute. This is generally a waste of bandwidth as, more often than not, the exact same result will be returned.

То есть, не стоит делать **семантически идентичные запросы** чаще чем раз в минуту.

Поэтому, для вашего скрипта правильным ограничением будет не 30 запросов в секунду, **а 1 запрос в минуту**. Что, на мой взгляд, является более чем адекватным ограничением для поставленной цели проверки наличия задач в очередях проверок.